# An eigenvector with irrational ratios of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose there exists $u =\begin{pmatrix} u_{1}\\ u_{2}\\ \vdots \\u_{n}\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Au = u$ and $\frac{u_{i}}{u_{j}}$ is irrational for some $i$ and $j$ in $\{1, 2, .., n \}$. Prove that there exists another $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Av = v$, but $v$ is not proportional to $u$.

Here is my thinking on this: 
Since $\frac{u_{i}}{u_{j}}$ is irrational for some $i$ and $j$, we can find some fixed $k$ such that $u_{k} \neq 0, 1$. Then letting $v = u_{k}^{-1}u$ satisfies $Av = v$. The shortcoming here is that $v$ is a scalar multiple of $u$. I would appreciate a quick fix to this or a better argument.

Comment: The only assumption you have made on the $u_i$ is that some ratio is an algebraic number. Well, 17 is an algebraic number, so I don't see how you get to "Since $u_1/u_j$ is irrational...."

Comment: It is a notational confusion, but I meant irrational in both cases.

Comment: Then maybe you should edit the question, so it says what you mean instead of saying something else.

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: It is fixed, but instead of $\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$, I had it as $\mathbb{Q}^{c}$, which I would think it is a symbol for irrational numbers too.

Comment: Ah, I was reading that symbol as the *closure* of the rationals, but you meant it as the *complement* of the rationals. Sometimes, it's better to write things out in words, so there's no danger of misinterpreting symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Scalar multiple" is the same as "proportional", so that's a no-go. And the key fact is that the entries of $A$ are integers, which you are not using.

Because $(A-I)u=0$, we know that $\det (A-I)=0$.

We are looking for a solution of $Av=v$, or $(A-I)v=0$. Since all the entries of $A$ are rational (integer in fact, but rational suffices), we can solve the system $(A-I)v$, and get a nonzero $v$ (since $\det (A-I)=0$) via Gaussian elimination. By construction, all entries of $v$ will be rational.

Now suppose that $v=\lambda u$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. In particular, 
$$
v_i=\lambda u_i,\ \ \ v_j=\lambda u_j.
$$
So
$$
\frac{v_i}{v_j}=\frac{\lambda u_i}{\lambda u_j}=\frac{u_i}{u_j}\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q.
$$
But this is impossible, because $v_i/v_j\in\mathbb Q$. It follows that $\lambda$ cannot exist, and $v$ is not a scalar multiple of $u$.

Comment: Indeed, both times. Thanks :)